# What versions of C and C++ standards does FlasCC support?

Tags: c++, c, flascc

I heard of FlasCC which is a C/C++ compiler targets AVM2. And also I heard it is based on an older version of GCC. (4.2??)

What kind/versions of C and C++ standards are supported on FlasCC?

Comment: C and C++ are different languages.

Comment: I took the liberty to edit the question to separate C from C++ where relevant. I hope this is not incompatible with what you are trying to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per http://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/flascc/docs/Reference.html it use standard GCC 4.2 http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.2.1/gcc/, which should answer your query!

You can look at "Introduction" section of above GCC link to know what is supported in this compiler.